# Something wrong with my ScrollView

Tags: android

I am having some issues with my scroll view. the code i am giving below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">
       <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/fabm"
        /> 
        <ImageView 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ac"
         />  
        <ImageView 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mbm"
         />
        <ImageView 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sk"
         />
        <ImageView 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/dcm"
         />
        <ImageView 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/eks"
        />
</ScrollView>
```

The application crashes when the activity starts, but when i am removing the scroll view the application is running smoothly.

Any help will be appriciated

Comment: If there's a crash, there's a stacktrace in logcat. Include it in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ScrollView` can have only one child and you have multiple. Put the children in e.g. a `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView`, e.g.

```
ScrollView
  LinearLayout
    ImageViews
```